# How can I stop the Alarm when application goes back to previous activity

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

in my application I am getting geo location based on alarm setting using commonsware library, things are working good but when I pressing the back button then at that time I want to stop that alarm and dont want to fetch the geo location.

How can I do this. Below is the code I am using to fetch the location based on alarm.

```
  private PendingIntent pendingIntent =null;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager =null;
    private void initLocationTracker()
    {
        try{
            mgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent i=new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);

            i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_INTENT,
                    new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class));
            i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_PROVIDER,
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
            mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                    PERIOD,
                    pi);

            Toast
                    .makeText(this,
                            "Location polling every 30 minutes begun",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String s = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "in my application I am getting geo location based on alarm setting using commonsware library, things are working good but when I pressing the back button then at that time I want to stop that alarm and dont want to fetch the geo location." -- this does not sound like a valid use of the `LocationPoller`. `LocationPoller` is designed to be used in the background, using `AlarmManager`. It is not designed to be used by a foreground application. Please use `LocationManager` directly for use in a foreground application.

Comment: For future reference, you can cancel an alarm by simply calling [`AlarmManger#cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) with the previous PendingIntent.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare I forgot that its for background polling